# How do I find $m$ so that the entire graph of the given function will be above the $x$-axis?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$y=x^2-mx+m+3$$

I understand that I need $x^{ 2 }-mx+m+3>0$, however, I don't know how to work with the given second unknown, $m$, that would allow me to figure out the given intervals.

Hints help me much more than the actual solution. So, no actual solution, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

The graph is a parabola and is all above the $x$ axis if it has no intersection with such axis, i.e if the equation $x^2-mx+m+3=0$ has no real solutions, and this is true iff the discriminant $\Delta=b^2-4ac <0$.

Can you solve from here ?

Comment: *** "$... = 3$ has no real solutions..." (oops)  "$ = 0$", that is

Comment: $\Delta=m^2-4m-12 <0$ . Can you solve for $m$ this inequality?

Comment: Yes, this makes a lot of sense now. I didn't even realize that they meant it was an equation with no real solutions.

Comment: Well, a little caution: the equation $p(x) = 0$ has no real solutions, where $p(x) = x^2−mx+m+3$, but $p$ is function that maps reals to reals, so it has a graph. The form of the quadratic shows that it's a parabola, and the coefficient of $x$, namely $a = 1$, is positive, so it opens upward. You just have to find $m$ so that the graph doesn't touch the $x$ axis (which amounts to finding $m$ such that the equation has no real roots). Sorry if this is all obvious now & I'm being horribly pedantic :)

Comment: No, it makes sense. I appreciate the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Complete the square:
$$ y= \left(x-\frac{m}{2} \right)^2 - \frac{m^2}{4}+m+3 $$
Now, the first term is nonnegative, so you now have to find the $m$ so that $- \frac{m^2}{4}+m+3>0$, which you can do by completing the square again, on $- \frac{m^2}{4}+m+3$!